# Why does part of the color gets removed in a draw function with a vector2 and a rectangle

Tags: c#, xna

When I draw a sprite like: `spriteBatch.Draw(textureMap0, mapPos0, rectMap0, Color.White);` the `rectMap0` sprite loses the color, and only one type of color stays. This is how the rectangle is set up:

```
        if (mapPos0.X == 350)
            rectMap0 = new Rectangle((int)mapPos0.X, (int)mapPos0.Y, textureMap0.Width, textureMap0.Height);
        else
            rectMap0 = new Rectangle((int)mapPos0.X, (int)mapPos0.Y, textureMap0.Width / 2, textureMap0.Height / 2);
```

This: 
[image]

Instead of: 
[image]

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code you posted, the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: try using some collorfull and rich of details texture. it looks your are rendering only part of original image.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a source rectangle in your draw, so that is probably too small or not displaying the right part.

Try Adding:

```
Console.WriteLine(rectMap0.ToString());
```

The Line before the `.Draw()` Call so you can check the specifications of your rectangle.

If you want to draw the entire image remember you can use `null` as the arguement is `nullable`.